# How to use correctly JSON.stringify with an PHP returned JS object

Tags: javascript, php, json, stringify

I have a `php` script which executes a `python` script and I got back an object like this:

```
{'data': [{'article title', 'article description', 'timestamp', 'weburl'}], 'status': 200, 'answers': [1]}
```

As I know I have to transform this into a `javascript JSON` from a `javascript object` type.

And I tried like

```js
myjs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(answer))
```

and

```js
JSON.stringify(answer)
```

or even just concatenate with `"`on the beginning and at the end. But neither got me a good result. So what is the correct way? or should I change something on php side?

The `php` part is simply this:

```php
    if ($_GET['times'] == 0) {
        $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 feed.py '. $_GET['subject']);
        $output = json_encode(shell_exec($command));
        
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo $output;
    }
```

This is in my `python` script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import json 
import html
import sys

requestpost = requests.post('NewsSource')
response_data = requestpost.json()

data = []
status = 0
answers = 0
out = {"data":[], "status":[], "answers":[0]}


searchterm = sys.argv[1]

error = 0

if requestpost.status_code == 200:
    out["status"] = 200
    for news in response_data["news"]:
        try:
            currentNews = json.loads(news)
            if ((html.unescape(currentNews["title"]) != "Array" and html.unescape(currentNews["title"]).lower().find(searchterm.lower()) != -1) or (html.unescape(currentNews["description"]).lower().find(searchterm.lower()) != -1)):         
                outnews = {html.unescape(currentNews["timestamp"]), html.unescape(currentNews["title"]), html.unescape(currentNews["description"]), html.unescape(currentNews["link"])}
                out["data"].append(outnews)
                out["answers"][0] = out["answers"][0] +1
        except:
            error += 1
else:
    out["status"] = 404

print (out)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Can you fix the the Python program to print JSON instead of Python format?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in PHP to parse Python data.

Comment: @Spectric if I try to get the values I got `undefined`

Comment: It's not JSON, none of the json_XXX functions will help with this.

Comment: You could try replacing all the `'` with `"` and calling `json_decode()`. But that could fail if there are embedded quotes in any of the strings.

Comment: @Barmar yes I can edit the python script, but what should I change? As I know the php part return a php type json.

Comment: Change the Python script to do `print(json.dumps(dictionary))` instead of `print(dictionary)`

Comment: @Barmar I've updated the question with python part, if I should edit that part

Comment: Actually, you can skip the PHP. Let the Python scripts talk to each other.

Comment: @Raptor can you give me an example without flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Python script so it prints JSON instead of Python format.

```
print(json.dumps(out))
```

However, sets aren't in JSON, so change `outnews` to a list.

```
outnews = [html.unescape(currentNews["timestamp"]), html.unescape(currentNews["title"]), html.unescape(currentNews["description"]), html.unescape(currentNews["link"])]
```

Then the PHP script can simply return that to the client.

```
    if ($_GET['times'] == 0) {
        $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 feed.py '. $_GET['subject']);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        passthru($command);
    }
```

If `passthru()` isn't working, you can try with your original `shell_exec()`. You don't need to call `json_encode()` because it's already encoded.

```
    if ($_GET['times'] == 0) {
        $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 feed.py '. $_GET['subject']);
        $output = shell_exec($command);
        
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: The `.js` part is stucked, even didn't get the answer. There is no console error, or PHP error.

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of the console for the response to this AJAX?

Comment: transferred 272 B size 0 B

Comment: Check your PHP error log for problems.

Comment: I tried again, maybe some copy misstype was last time, but I got this PHP error: `Uncaught ValueError: passthru(): Argument #1 ($command) cannot be empty` and `500 Server error` on console.

Comment: I can't see any reason why `$command` would be empty.

Comment: and if empty why I can't get even `null`?

Comment: As the error message says, the command line can't be empty.

Comment: If the command is empty, it reports that error, it doesn't print anything, so why would you expect `null`?

Comment: are you sure that this would run the python script without `escapeshellcmd()` or any other command line call?

Comment: I thought that the default value will be `null` or some memory junk.

Comment: I used `escapeshellarg()` since only the `$_GET` parameter needs to be escaped. But you can try it with `escapeshellcmd()` like your original script.

Comment: The value isn't being printed, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you understand what `passthru()` does? It runs the command, and just passes its output through to the client.

Comment: Yes, I see it on the php manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php but then why I can't get anything?

Comment: I don't know. If it worked with `shell_exec()` it should also work with `passthru()`

Comment: Try the alternate version I just added.

Comment: Also 271-0 on network tab and nothing on console or on PHP error log

Comment: If you run the Python script by hand, do you get the JSON output?

Comment: with `print (out)` I got what is in the question and with `print(json.dumps(out))` I got `TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Change `outnews` to a list. See the edit

Comment: Ok, but it is initialized like `out = {"data":[], "status":[], "answers":[0]}` and it is filled up using this.

Comment: That's not a problem, those are all lists.

Comment: `out` is a dictionary, not a set.

Comment: The only set in the code is `outnews`

Comment: Than I got back a valid JSON, but the php part also 271-0

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how that could happen. PHP is clearly echoing what the Python script returned, I don't see how the valid JSON could turn into 0 bytes.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're going through the PHP script in the first place? Can't you enable CGI on the server so you can call the Python script directly?

Answer (score 0):

Also If I want to get back all news than change `out` and return it back like this:

```py
out = []

error = 0
status = 0
nrOfResults = 0

if requestpost.status_code == 200:
    status = 200
    for news in response_data["news"]:
        try:
            currentNews = json.loads(news)
            if ((html.unescape(currentNews["title"]) != "Array" and html.unescape(currentNews["title"]).lower().find(searchterm.lower()) != -1) or (html.unescape(currentNews["description"]).lower().find(searchterm.lower()) != -1)):         
                outnews = [html.unescape(currentNews["timestamp"]), html.unescape(currentNews["title"]), html.unescape(currentNews["description"]), html.unescape(currentNews["link"])]
                out.append(outnews)
                nrOfResults = nrOfResults +1
        except:
            error += 1
else:
    status = 404

out.append(status)
out.append(nrOfResults)

#outnews = [html.unescape(currentNews["timestamp"]), html.unescape(currentNews["title"]), html.unescape(currentNews["description"]), html.unescape(currentNews["link"])]
print(json.dumps(out))
```

than the last element of `js` array will be a the number of results and the before one will be the status of the source link.